# Using Linq to query Entity Framework with Where clause and many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables `People` and `Orders`and a many-to-many relationship between the two using `PeopleOrders`.

Each order is associated with two people: `Client` and `Salesman`.

I have the following query:

```
var query = db.People
              .Where(u => u.Description.Equals("Client"))
              .Select(u => new {u.Id, OrderId = u.Orders.Select(p => p.Id))
})
              .ToList();
```

This returns a json like this:

```
[{"Id":1,"OrderId":[2]},{"Id":9,"OrderId":[10,11,12,13]},{"Id":14,"OrderId":[14,15]}]
```

The `ClientID` and an array of orders.

I need to invert. Orders can't be an array.

So I need `OrderID` associated with the `ClientID`. Something like this:

```
[{"OrderId":2,"Id":1},{"OrderId":10,"Id":9},{"OrderId":11,"Id":9},{"OrderId":12,"Id":9},{"OrderId":13,"Id":9}]
```

The query would be something like:

```
var query = db.Orders
```

But I need to subquery the People table, so it return only Client; otherwise, it will return a array of People like:

```
{"OrderId":2,"Id":[1,10]}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var query = db.People
.Where(u => u.Description.Equals("Client"))
.SelectMany(u =>  u.Orders.Select(p => new {u.Id, p.OrderId}))
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this (using `SelectMany`, in order you flatten the projection of your data):

```
var query = db.People
              .Where(person => person.Description.Equals("Client"))
              .Select(person => new 
              { 
                  PersonOrders = person.Orders
                                       .Select(order => new 
                                       { 
                                           PersonId = person.Id, 
                                           OrderId = order.Id))
                                       })
              })
              .SelectMany(x=>x.PersonOrders)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: @Migu3litto You are welcome. I am glad that I helped :) !